# Reverse page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, sorting, lastpage

How can one make LaTeX print the pages numbering in reverse order, in the sense that if the document in question has N pages then the first page is numbered N, then N-1, ...?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Charles: I'd assume it's for an (boring) continuum mechanics textbook or similarly complex discipline, so that the students have an idea how many pages are there left for them to read..

Comment: @Martin: This sounds depressingly plausible.

Comment: Too good question, I am that person who likes to have reverse page numbering, it is very motivating to read a book with this numbering.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I in fact did exactly this while publishing a Hebrew-English book which opens both LTR and RTL and has continuous page numbering throughout.  It was easiest to work on the two sections separately and then combine them with pdftk.  I needed a way to make the page numbers on one side run backwards and continue from where the other side left off.  Quite handy.

Comment: Your question is not wholly clear on whether you want the content also provided in reverse order or not.  If one did want the content order also reversed, then this question is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244706/reverse-the-page-order-in-the-whole-document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea:

1. Run the the *tex compilation as usual, and calculate the number of pages.
2. On the second run, customize the page number to be shown as `TotalPageNum-CurrentPagenum+1` (calculated by a formula, that is).
3. There is no step 3.

You probably can skip doing this until your document is finished, so that this is a one-off operation.

There are so many things that might be unfeasible or outright difficult, but perhaps that could work. At least, this is not likely to be dependent on a particular document class.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution you can use for `book` class documents.  It counts down the remaining pages from `\mainmatter` to the last page, ignoring pages in the `\frontmatter` division (mainly because I didn't want to overcomplicate things with roman numbering, but still wanted to provide an answer that recognised the issue).  You'll obviously need to adjust this answer for non-`book` class documents (`article`, `report`, etc.; `memoir` and `KOMA` class documents are probably a whole new kettle of fish for which this solution is likely to prove unsuitable).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \oldmainmatter%
  \pagestyle{fancy}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}%
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{Page \thepage\ of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}%
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{Remaining Pages \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}-\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \chapter{Front Matter}
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \lipsum[1-15]
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will `\pageref` work correctly with this solution?  It looks to me like the page number displayed won't match the references.

Answer (score 2):

You have already received good answers for your questions, but I'd like to mention another way of getting around **boring page numbering**, or in general, boring display of any counter. I think that sometimes it is a better idea to display a counter visually. For example, consider this five page document:

[image]

The four counters on headers and footers visually display the current page number (for some styles, they also give an indication of remaining page numbers). This is inspired by the styles used in ConTeXt presentation modules and some beamer styles.

The above example is based on a ConTeXt [module](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) that I have written. It uses metapost to draw the counters (and only works with ConTeXt MkIV). For LaTeX, one can use the same idea and use tikz as a backend.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to do this and I found a simple solution, based on Martin Tapankov's answer, which didn't require manual intervention.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[pagespersheet=1]{totpages}
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr 1+\TotSheets-\the\value{page}\relax}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

The advantage of modifying `\thepage` as opposed to just changing the page number display in the header/footer is that `\label` and `\pageref` work as expected.

Comment: I confirm that this works, and its so simple relative to the other answers. Sometimes it's worth scrolling down to the last answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [answer of Geoffrey Jones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6038/6865) (+1 for his answer), for different numbering schemes you could use (some of) this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{refcount}% only necessary if some page numbering scheme
                     % is used more than once
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Page "\thepage{}" (\theCurrentPageLocal{}) of %
 \lastpageref{pagesLTS.\pagesLTS@pnc} %
 (total \theCurrentPage{} of \lastpageref{LastPages})}%
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Remaining Pages %
%  % If each page numbering scheme (roman, arabic,...) is used just once, 
%  % it is sufficient: 
%\@tempcnta=\value{pagesLTS.\pagesLTS@pnc.1.local.cnt}\relax%
%  % otherwise it is necessary: 
\@tempcnta=\getpagerefnumber{pagesLTS.\pagesLTS@pnc.local}\relax%
\advance\@tempcnta by -\theCurrentPageLocal%
\xdef\Remaining{\the\@tempcnta}%
\Remaining{} of \lastpageref{pagesLTS.\pagesLTS@pnc} %
(in total %
\@tempcnta=\value{pagesLTS.pagenr}\relax%
\advance\@tempcnta by -\theCurrentPage%
\xdef\Remaining{\the\@tempcnta}%
\Remaining%
)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Front Matter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\lipsum[1-10]
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```