# Reverse the page order in the whole document

Tags: formatting

I am looking for a simple way to reverse the whole document's page order.
So first page becomes page 7, second page 6, ..., seventh page 1.

Is there an easier way than reversing it afterwards using PDF printers or something else?

Comment: Try [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) : `pdftk in.pdf cat end-1 output reversed.pdf`

Comment: Are you talking about just reversing the order of the physical pages, or are you talking about having LaTeX renumber the pages in reverse order?  For example the book A (p1), B(p2), C(p3) could be presented as C(p3), B(p2), A(p1) or as A(p3), B(p2), C(p1), or several other possibilities.  What is it exactly you seek?

Comment: Physical Pages. So, I suppose, C(p3), B(p2), A(p1)

Comment: That would seem a lot easier to do after and outside of LaTeX (as postprocessing).

Comment: I thought a task as trivial as that would be extremely easy in LaTeX, as long as you know the command.
Thank you for your input!

Comment: It could be done with two separate LaTeX compilations.  First, generate the normal document.  Them use the `pdfpages` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to extract those pages in reverse order, creating a new document.

Answer (score 5):

This approach takes two separate LaTeX compilations.  First, compile your test document in the normal way.

For example, let this be `testfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\scalebox{35}{A}\clearpage
\scalebox{35}{B}\clearpage
\scalebox{35}{C}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Compile it, producing `testfile.pdf`.

Then compile the following MWE (changing the input-filename from testfile.pdf, as appropriate).  The output of this compilation will produce a PDF in which the pages of your original document are reversed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=last-1]{testfile.pdf}
\end{document}
```