# foliation of pages in Hebrew

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, hebrew

I'm making a book in Hebrew and I need that the foliate is generated backwards, for example in a book of 320 pages, should be foliar: 320, 319, 318, 317, ... ... 4, 3, 2, 1.

There is some special technique for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to normally generate the documnet and then make a second one using `pdfpages` with `includepdf[pages=last-1]{normal-doc}`.

Comment: Doesn't babel and XeLaTeX already take care of that?

Comment: it is not possible to achieve what I am looking for with pdfpages, since the cross references (\ref and \pageref) inside the book are poorly structured

Comment: Did you see this Q&A? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/reverse-page-numbering